# How to find the "href" of a <ul> a particular frame?

Tags: java, selenium, automation

[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jj4Pn.jpg) I am trying to get the "href" of a particular frame which you can find in the image , i tried as much as i can but i am not able to get the "href"

```
List<WebElement> list=d.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='collegeFilter']/div/div/div/div/div/div[13]/div"));
                   for(WebElement e : list){
                       String link = e.getAttribute("href");
                       System.out.println(link);
```

I tried the above code , i took the Xpath of that frame and tried to get the href of that frame . Link: http://freevideolectures.com/Subject/Business-Management  [image]

Comment: @DebanjanB  Sir Kindly help me out .

Comment: please check my answer, it may help you.

Comment: Ul tag is not having any href property.

Comment: That's an error-prone selector if I ever saw one. Is there really no other features to that element other than going down the divs and then selecting 13th element? Can you also post an example HTML (not necessarily taken from that site) that would exhibit your problem and not make us look at third party sites (which might change at any time and make answers useless for future readers)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the `"href"` attribute of page numbers at the bottom of the page you can use the following code block :

```
List<WebElement> list = d.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='pagination']/li/a"));
    for(WebElement e : list)
        System.out.println(e.getAttribute("href"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath is pointing to top element which doesn't have href property. you can try with following it may help you.

```
List<WebElement> list=d.findElements(By.xpath(".//*[@id='collegeFilter']/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/figure/a"));
for(WebElement e : list){
       String link = e.getAttribute("href");
       System.out.println(link);
 }
```

Comment: thank you fpr the help bro , but I am trying to get the herf of the page number frame at the bottom of the page  . look at the image which i just posted  .